# Try Catch block should inserted in Controller or Model?

Tags: php, api, rest, pdo

I have a structure project like follow:

```
/Controller
    test.php
/Models
    test_model.php
```

Now when I execute a request the model `test.php` shunk the request in the corresponding model, in this case `test_model.php`. Here no problem. Now my question is: I should handle the exceptino in `test.php` class (controller) or in the `test_model.php` class?

For execute all the database dialogue I have created a db layer with pdo.
I set the:

```
$this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

for handle the exception. All working good but I have this doubt. A practice example:

```
<?php

    include "test_model.php";

    public function selectInformation()
    {
        try
        {
            $test = new Test_Model(); //just as example..
            return $test->selectUserInfo(); // test_model
        }catch(Exception $ex)
        {
              echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "message" => $ex->getMessage()));
              exit();
        }
    }

    ...
```

Here the `Test_Model` class:

```
   <?php

      class Test_Model extends PDO
      {

         public function __construct()
         {
               parent::__construct();
               $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
               $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
         }

         public function selectUserInfo()
         {
             //I removed most part of the code, essentially here an exception is fired by a non correct db table name
         }
```

Actually I manage all the exceptions in the `Test` class but is a good practice? I use each `Model` only for return a result from the database. There is no each in the `Model` class actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither in the model or controller.

An error exception have to be handled in the **error handler.**

Instead of "handling" every call to the model separately, you have to handle all errors in a single place. Which is called error handler.

Neither error message or line number should be sent in JSON. This information have to be **logged** locally, while no internal error have to be revealed outside. Only a generalized excuse have to be shown.

There should be an error handler set through [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) that have to be responsible for handling errors. It should log errors in production, while only a generalized excuse sent outside.

Note that it is very important to send appropriate HTTP status code in case of error, of 5xx family

Comment: Okay got it, thanks for this suggest. The error handler should be included in the Model parent? How I can fire the error handler automatically? Could you explain with a bit example please? Thanks.

Comment: It should be set in the application core.

Comment: Okay, well I already have my own log class that write the stack trace of the system. But didn't atuomatically, for write error on the log file I need to call the static method: `LOG::instance()->warning('pass the exception here')` So at this point I should manage the exception in the controller and call my SingleTon library. Also in the exception I need to modify the header, it's good?

Comment: If you want to add a call to your log class several hundred times in your code, then it doesn't really matter which particular part you want to litter. Neither will be good.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the try catch block inside your controller.

Comment: Okay actually the error printed is like this: `{
"success": false
"message": "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test_db.table_db' doesn't exist"
}` If I want also print the line of the class that has generated the error?

Comment: @Sandokan why an API user should be concerned with a number of line where an error occurred? Do they have an access to the code base to make any use of the line number?

Comment: @YourCommonSense the error code line is displayed only in production. I have a condition that check if a constant is defined, if yes the stack trace must be printed against not 'cause we aren't in production.

Comment: @Sandokan I can't get the meaning of your comment, but there is no point in displaying a line number in production.